# Display single data dynamically after login in angular 7

Tags: angular

Id Undefined If I load page the data . I should get user data for one record dynamically after login in home page .

```
ngOnInit() {
this.loadUser(this.route.snapshot.params['id']);
}
loadUser(id) {
this.userService.getBook(id).pipe(first()).subscribe(users => {
this.loadUser(id);  
});
}
```

Id Undefined error

Comment: your URI should be /something/1, in your *.module.ts add in routes { path: 'simething/:id' }

Comment: @erajuan that is a good way to go about it as well, just all depends on the logical flow of the website

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a tricky thing if you're new to Angular, it all boils down to when the "routing" event has finished, and the data is available.

Thankfully, Angular has some built in stuff that helps with managing these sorts of tasks.

#### Waiting for routing to finish

In the constructor for your AppComponent above, you need to subscribe to the routing events, and wait for the event `NavigationEnd`.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
   this.router.events.subscribe(event => {
       if (event instanceof NavigationEnd ) {
           // Parse your userId from the event.urlAfterRedirects string here
           // (note: the parse thing below is just an example, not a real function)
           const id = parse(event.urlAfterRedirects);

           this.loadData(id);
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a more reactive approach to this and use the async pipe to subscribe in the template:

```
   bookById$: Observable<any>;
   constructor(
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private userService: UserService
   ) {
      this.bookById$ = this.activeRoute.params.pipe(
         map(params => params.id),
         switchMap((id) => this.userService.getBook(id))))
    );
```

and your template would use the async pipe with ng-container:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="bookById$ | async as book">
   {{ book }}
</ng-container>
```

Some people might not like the $ for observable convention but I do... so shush.

Comment: getting error for ID message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "undefined" at path "_id" for model "Student""

Comment: without really knowing your data model and seeing the actual code, it's hard to debug. maybe make a repro on stackblitz or something?